# Fancytree: Configure my own keyboard navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, treeview, fancytree

I would like to know if there is a way to expand on the navigation that Fancytree offers, for instance, force the `delete`, `cut`, `copy` or `paste` methods from my contextMenu to occur when I press `Delete`, `ctrl+x`, `ctrl+c` or `ctrl+v` on my keyboard. I've been studying and using fancytree for a few weeks now and I haven't found this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example browser has a demo for this:
http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/#sample-multi-ext.html

Comment: That's awesome, thanks man. I'd like to know one more thing... Is there a way to automatically highlight the entire title of the node when you do an inline edit?

Comment: **nevermind** `edit: function(event, data){data.input.select();}`